# Prevent Entra ID /authorize endpoint from logging users to other microsoft services

Tags: single-sign-on, microsoft-entra-id

We want to use entra id as an OIDC provider to log in users to our applications. However, our use case requires that when users log in (on the https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../oauth2/v2.0/authorize page) they are not logged in to other microsoft services (such as Office365), but only redirected to our app with an authorization code so we can request ID tokens and access tokens for our app only.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Are you using Entra ID or B2C?

Comment: I am using Entra ID